# c# setting datatype during runtime from string

Tags: c#, reflection

Lets say for the below code:

```
public class FieldData
{
    public int Field1 {get; set;}
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
    public bool Field3 {get; set;}
}

var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FieldData>(jsonString);
```

I want to set the value of "FieldData" that was passed DeserializeObject dynamically from a string, is that possible? i read about reflection but i cant figure it out, so I am looking for something like the below:

```
string dataType="FieldData";
var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dataType>(jsonString);
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, Type.GetType(dataType))` although you probably need the fully qualified type name

Comment: To understand why this is not possible, think of the type of `obj1`. Keyword `var` is a stand-in for a strong type `dataType`, so it needs to be known at compile time. The best you can do is `object obj1 = ...` if you are willing to do some reflection calls, but making a strongly-typed variable for a runtime type is not possible.